# How can I mark some ScalaTests so that they only execute when invoked explicitly

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I'm new to SBT and scalatest but am wondering how I get some of my `org.scalatest._` tests to only execute "on demand".

In SBT I can invoke all of the Unit Tests like `sbt:Sprout> test`, or all of the IntegrationTests like `sbt:Sprout> it:test`.  I need a way to annotate the tests that allows an `sbt:Sprout test` invocation to skip them but with some other invocation executes ONLY these tests.  Scalatest docs speak of some `sbt:Sprout> test-only *RedSuite` invocation to allow me to "Categorize" my tests, but its not clear how to leverage that so they DON'T run as Unit Tests.  `org.scalatest.Tag`s alone do not get it off the "default" of getting executed when `sbt:Sprout> test`.  I need these to be `ignored` unless invoked explicitly.

Is this use case possible in ScalaTest through SBT?

Answer (score 4):

> You can specify tag names of tests to include or exclude from a run. To specify tags to include, use -n followed by a list of tag names to include. Similarly, to specify tags to exclude, use -l followed by a list of tag names to exclude

(please look [here](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_sbt) for more info in the official documents).

For example:

```
package com.test

import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.Tag

object IncludeTest extends Tag("com.tags.Include")
object ExcludeTest extends Tag("com.tags.Exclude")

class TestSuite extends FlatSpec {

 "Test1" taggedAs(IncludeTest) in {
   val sum = 1 + 1
   assert(sum === 2)
  }

 "Test2" taggedAs(ExcludeTest) in {
   val minus = 2 - 1
   assert(minus === 1)
 }
}
```

To include `IncludeTest` and exclude `ExcludeTest` tag, you should do:

```
test-only org.* -- -n com.tags.Include -l com.tags.Exclude
```

Comment: Shucks.  The tag doesn't get it off the "This test will run by default when Unit tests run" path.  I need tests tagged in this manner to NOT run when `sbt:Sprout> test` without the ceremony of a tagging system.  I don't want to force all the other developers to have to change their `sbt:Sprout> test` invocation to account for these tagged tests.  Kind-of ditto for the `sbt:Sprout>it:test` invocation.  There's got to be a way to do this.  Is there a way for me to become like `sbt:Sprout> specialTest:test`?

Comment: Maybe this `@DoNotDiscover // Disable discovery of a test class` annotation is all I really need.  I'm just trying to get some of my tests off the "run this test all the time" behavior of `test` and/or `it:test`

Answer (score 4):

[`assume`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/index.html#org.scalatest.Assertions@assume(condition:Boolean,clue:Any)(implicitprettifier:org.scalactic.Prettifier,implicitpos:org.scalactic.source.Position):org.scalatest.Assertion) assertion specified inside a [fixture-context object](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_fixtures#fixtureContextObjects) could be used to implement conditional-ignore semantics dependant on environmental flag. For example, consider the following `IfIgnored` fixture

```
trait IfIgnored extends Assertions {
  assume(System.getenv("runIgnoredTest").toBoolean, "!!! TEST IGNORED !!!")
}
```

which can be instantiated like so

```
it should "not say goodbye" in new IfIgnored  {
  Hello.greeting shouldNot be ("goodbye")
}
```

Now if we define the following settings in `build.sbt`

```
Test / fork := true,
Test / envVars := Map("runIgnoredTest" -> "false")
```

and the following tests

```
class HelloSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  "The Hello object" should "say hello" in {
    Hello.greeting shouldEqual "hello"
  }

  it should "not say goodbye" in new IfIgnored  {
    Hello.greeting shouldNot be ("goodbye")
  }

  it should "not say live long and prosper" in new IfIgnored {
    Hello.greeting shouldNot be ("live long and prosper")
  }
}
```

then executing `sbt test` should output

```
[info] HelloSpec:
[info] The Hello object
[info] - should say hello
[info] - should not say goodbye !!! CANCELED !!!
[info]   scala.Predef.augmentString(java.lang.System.getenv("runIgnoredTest")).toBoolean was false !!! TEST IGNORED !!! (HelloSpec.scala:6)
[info] - should not say live long and prosper !!! CANCELED !!!
[info]   scala.Predef.augmentString(java.lang.System.getenv("runIgnoredTest")).toBoolean was false !!! TEST IGNORED !!! (HelloSpec.scala:6)
[info] Run completed in 2 seconds, 389 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 1
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 1, failed 0, canceled 2, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
```

where we see only `should say hello` ran whilst the rest were ignored.

To execute only ignored tests we could define the following custom command `testOnlyIgnored`:

```
commands += Command.command("testOnlyIgnored") { state =>
  val ignoredTests = List(
    """"should not say goodbye"""",
    """"should not say live long and prosper""""
  ).mkString("-z ", " -z ", "")

  """set Test / envVars := Map("runIgnoredTest" -> "true")""" ::
    s"""testOnly -- $ignoredTests""" :: state
}
```

Note how we are making use of [`-z`](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner#selectingSuitesAndTests) runner argument to run particular tests, for example,

```
testOnly -- -z "should not say goodbye" -z "should not say live long and prosper"
```

Also note how we are manually adding test names to `ignoredTests`. Now executing `sbt testOnlyIgnored` should output

```
[info] HelloSpec:
[info] The Hello object
[info] - should not say goodbye
[info] - should not say live long and prosper
[info] Run completed in 2 seconds, 298 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 2
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 2, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
```

where we see `should say hello` was not run whilst all the ignored tests ran.

If we drop the requirement of having to run ignored tests separately, then we can use provided [`ignore`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.0/index.html#org.scalatest.Ignore) annotation like so

```
ignore should "not say goodbye" in {
  Hello.greeting shouldNot be ("goodbye")
}
```

which on `sbt test` outputs

```
[info] HelloSpec:
[info] The Hello object
[info] - should say hello
[info] - should not say goodbye !!! IGNORED !!!
[info] - should not say live long and prosper !!! IGNORED !!!
[info] Run completed in 2 seconds, 750 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 1
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 1, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 2, pending 0
```

Comment: Hmm.  That's clever, to be sure, but a lot more work than I thought it would take.  I'm kind-of surprised support for something like this isn't just built in.  I'm thinking the tests I'm speaking of are just going to become `InterationTest`s rather than go through ScalaTest backflips.